# Why/when multiple roots of a polynomial corresponds to contracting loops on its complex image?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

This geometrical question arose while thinking/reading on the geometrical proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra.
In an old book by Pontryagin, it is said that multiple roots of a polynomial with real coefficients corresponds to contracting loops.

Conjugate roots may correspond to passing the origin by crossings, like in
$f(z)=(z+2)(z-I)(z+I)$:
[image: complex image of f value]

Do always multiple roots of polynomials with real coefficients correspond to contracting loops? Is it so for complex coefficients?
If the answer is not trivial, could you, please, provide any reference to textbooks (eng,rus,french)?

I guess that it could be easier seen from 3d-representation perspective.

Comment: What loop exactly are you considering here?

Comment: The (geometrical) loops that crossing/contracting the origin and correspond to multiple roots. On the figure you see a small one and a bigger 'heart-shaped' one.